# How to upload a dataframe as a stream without saving on disc?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-csv

I want to upload a dataframe to a server as csv file with Gzip encoding without saving it on the disc.

It is easy to build some csv file with Gzip encoding using `spark-csv` lib:

```
df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .save(s"result.csv.gz")
```

But I have no idea how to get `Array[Byte]`, representing my `DataFrame`, which I can upload via HTTP

Answer (score 3):

You could write to your remote server as a remote hdfs server, you'd need to have hdfs installed on your remote server but after that you should be able to do something like

```
df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .save("hdfs://your_remote_server_hostname_or_ip/result.csv.gz")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is that I need to upload files to storage like Google Drive. I can't install hdfs here)